# ApiController could not be found

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVvJX4CoLUY I have add the ***using System.Web; using System.Web.Http;*** but i still get the error state that apicontroller could no found, and so on, below picture is the error I face:

[image]

below is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace UploadToServer.Server.Controllers
{
public class UploadsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();

                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);

                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }

        return "no files";
    }
}
```

}

Anyone can share me ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the references in your project for those libraries. As per [svdoever](https://github.com/GuitarRich/sitecore.react.project/issues/1)  you can add the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` through NuGet  to fix this. For instructions on how to use NuGet, please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Your question have nothing to do with Xamarin.Forms but with WEB.API. Your Xamarin.Forms project cannot and should not contain any WEB.Api controllers. Your server side code should be in a separate project. The easiest way to do so is to create a separate project with a specific template.
Luckily Microsoft has a very easy to follow guides:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

However I would recommend you to use Asp.NET Core instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Comment: Hi, I apply this in xamarin form

Comment: Your Xamarin.Forms project cannot and should not contain any WEB.Api controllers. Your server side code should be in a separate project. Re-watch the youtube video.

Comment: Hi I have follow exactly the video did but now i only get HttpContext error, any way to overcome it?

Comment: Take a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595543/system-web-httpcontext-not-recognized

Comment: I'm following the Asp.NET tutorial and am getting the same issue. I'm not really sure how to fix this error based off of your post.

Answer (score 0):

You getting this error because packages required to run API are not installed.
Manually you have to download this package from nuget.org.

Follow below steps -

1. Check whether Nuget.ORG listed in Package Source.
   Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Setting -> Package Sources.
   If Nuget is not listed in Package Source then Add source as "http://nuget.org" and update.
2. Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
   Select Package source as "Nuget" and Click Restore

Same can be done by Right Click Your Solution file -> Manage Nuget Packages for solution.
Select Nuget in Package Source and restore.

Required packages will be downloaded from nuget.org